# ALBを経由したアクセスができない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, nginx, unicorn, amazon-elb

お世話になっております。
下記問題について知見のある方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示お願いします。

## 起きている問題

AWS環境で`Nginx+Unicorn+Rails`を実装し、`EC2`に`ALB`を経由してアクセスしようとしているのですが、
`ALB`の`DNS 名`でアクセスすると`Nginx`のデフォルトページが表示されてしまいます。
デプロイしている`Rails`のアプリケーションを開くためにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 確認したこと

nginxの構文を確認したところ、サーバー名の長さが上限を超えていました。（ALBのDNS名を設定しているため）

```
$ sudo nginx -t
[sudo] ryouya のパスワード:
nginx: [emerg] could not build server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 64
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

nginx設定ファイルに『server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;』を追記したいのですが、構文エラーになってしまいます。

```
#追記時のエラー_1
$ vi coffee_app.conf
：
server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name {ALBのDNS名};
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; ＃この一文を追記
：

$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] "server_names_hash_bucket_size" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/coffee_app.conf:15
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

#追記時のエラー_2
$ vi coffee_app.conf
:
http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; ＃この一文を追記
server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name {ALBのDNS名};
    keepalive_timeout 5;
:

$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/coffee_app.conf:10
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

## 関連ファイル

coffee_app.conf(nginx設定ファイル)

```
$ cat coffee_app.conf
error_log  /var/www/rails/coffee_app/log/nginx.error.log;
access_log /var/www/rails/coffee_app/log/nginx.access.log;

upstream unicorn_server {
    server unix:/var/www/rails/coffee_app/tmp/sockets/.unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name {ALBのDNS名};
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Location of our static files
    root /var/www/rails/coffee_app/public;

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
        root /var/www/rails/coffee_app/public;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /var/www/rails/coffee_app/public;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
    }    
}
```

unicorn.conf.rb

```
$ vi unicorn.conf.rb

  stdout_path $std_log
  timeout $timeout
  listen  $listen
  pid $pid
  # loading booster
  preload_app true
  # before starting processes
  before_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
    if old_pid != server.pid
      begin
        Process.kill "QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i
      rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      end
    end
  end
  # after finishing processes
  after_fork do |server, worker|
    defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
```

## 環境

Rails 5.1.6
Ruby 2.5.1
Unicorn 5.4.1
Nginx 1.12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。

■原因１
coffee_app.conf(nginx設定ファイル)のサーバー名がEC2のElastic IPアドレスを使用していた。
■解決方法
coffee_app.conf(nginx設定ファイル)のサーバー名をALBのDNS名に変更

■原因２
coffee_app.conf(nginx設定ファイル)のサーバー名がALBのDNS名のため長文でありNginxがエラーで起動しない
■解決方法
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf（nginxデフォルト設定ファイル）にserver_names_hash_bucket_size 128;を追記